# This circle only draws once in android

Tags: android

Why does this code only draw a circle once? I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Do I need to do some kind of refresh or something?  I am able to get a red dot, to draw once, but any click after does not show a new dot, or even move the previous one.

```
package ball.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BallActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

BallView bv;
int i = 0;
TextView tv;

//float x = 20;
//float y = 20;
float r = 20;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top);

    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    //main.addView(new BallView(this, 20, 20, 20));
    main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            i++;
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            tv.setText("Clicks: " + i + "X: " + x + "Y: " + y);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v;
            ll.addView(new BallView(ll.getContext(), x, y, 25));

            return false;
        }
    });
}
}


package ball.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.View;

public class BallView extends View{

Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

float x;// = 20; 
float y;// = 20;
float r;// = 20;

public BallView(Context context, float x, float y, float r) {
    super(context);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    //paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings on the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `LinearLayout` to an `AbsoluteLayout`. I think what's happening is that your first `BallView` is actually taking up the entirety of the `LinearLayout` view group and any other views you add to it are being pushed out of the layout.

Also, look into using `addView(View,  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)` instead, so you can set the size/position of the ball there as opposed to in `BallView.onDraw`, which will allow smaller regions of your layout to be marked dirty.

Comment: I agree, but I know that AbsoluteLayout is depracted. Android suggests using a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: I changed it to a frame layout and that solved my problem.  Thanks for the suggestions.